# How to add a method in jquery to match value with regular expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I am using Jquery validation plugin to validate fields. Now I am validating filed which takes academic year as input. I mean it should match values like `2013-2014`. For this I wrote a Jquery method as follow,

```
 $.validator.addMethod("academicYear",function (value,element){
  return value.match(/^[2-9]\d{3}\-[2-9]\d{3}$/);

 }, 'Please enter in correct format');
```

In validate method in rules I just have `academicYear : {required : true},`. Now it is just validating for required field, it accepts/validate if I give alphabets also. Is there anything wrong in this. If it is please help me.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<input class="myInputField"></input>


$('.myInputField').keyup(function(e){
  var val = $(this).val();
  var regexTest = /^\d{0,8}(\-\d{1,2})?$/;
  var ok = regexTest.test(val);
  if(ok) {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
  } else {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  }
});
```

Comment: its k but its not matching exactly "2013-2014"

Comment: kk .. how did u get value in input formate? '2013-2014' u entered input fields or dropdown list box

Comment: Thank u it worked but I changed regexp to `/^2[0-9]{3}\-2[0-9]{3}$/`